# How to update Status of Subscribers from Data Extention In Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, subscriber, subscriber-key, unsubscribe

I have a Data extention containig a list of Subscribers with their email and subscriber key. I want to update the records in the Data extention to the All Subscribers list from the Data Extention on a regular frequency automatically.

Also, I'm using version 2.0 of Marketing cloud org and need to update the subscriber status from only the specified business unit where the Data extention is present.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished by doing the following process:

1. Data Extract of your Data Extension
2. File Transfer to move this file output from Safehouse to SFMC SFTP
3. Import Activity of that file output into All Subscribers list.

During this, keep in mind that statuses such as 'held' and 'bounce' will not be added in via this method, they are only editable internally by SFMC and cannot be changed in All Subscribers by users. I would recommend having it only be 'Active' and 'Unsubscribed'.

Another Caveat is that All Subscribers is usually shared at an enterprise level (unless you have the correct settings in place) so you might want to review **[this doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_unsubscribe_settings.htm&type=5)** for more information on this.

Putting the above activities into an automation will allow you to schedule it to be run repeatedly.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I'm following the same approach but the only thing which is not working here is the last step "Import Activity of that file output into All Subscribers list.". I have done all the correct configurations as per the documentation and also, when I download the file created from File transfer from FTP, the file format is also correct , ie, .csv file with the all the headers as well. But when we run the automation all the steps runs successfully but the last step does not update the "All Subscribers" list in the Child BU.

Comment: @JiteshGoel - Does not update them how?

Comment: the .csv file is correctly created on the FTP import folder. but when the Automation is complete the update on the All Subscribers list does not happen with updating the Status of the Subscriber to "Unsubscribed" or "Unsubscribe"'(tried both values.)(I hope this you were refering to this in the above comment)

Comment: If you are following the guidelines here (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_update_subscriber_status.htm&type=5) then I would look at the rules/settings you have assigned to your BUs/Enterprise account to see if perhaps that is causing the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a Script Activity if the volumes of rows are reasonable.

I've set up a few unsub-resub scripts that update All Subscribers with instructions from a Data Extension that's updated on an interval.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Sems to be a good option but haven't implemented such kind of process in the past. Please can you share a reference doc or any refence screenshopt or anything which I can refer and implement it on our end.